# Abnormal mpi behaviour for large array

Tags: fortran, mpi

In the following code of array summation give me correct answer, when i use max_rows=10,100,1000,10000 , but when i use max_rows=100000 or more, i am getting abnormal answer and even i am getting negative partial sum from one of the proces.

```
program sum_vector
use mpi
implicit none 
integer,parameter::max_rows=100000
integer::myrank,master=0,ierr,status(mpi_status_size),num_procs
integer::i,rank,avg_rows_per_procs,sender
integer::num_rows_to_send,num_rows_to_receive,start_row,end_row,partial_sum,total_sum,st1,st2
integer,allocatable::vector(:),vector2(:)
allocate(vector(max_rows),stat=st1)
allocate(vector2(max_rows),stat=st2)
if(st1/=0 .or. st2/=0)then
    print*,'Cannot allocate'
    stop
end if 
call mpi_init(ierr)
call mpi_comm_rank(mpi_comm_world,myrank,ierr)
call mpi_comm_size(mpi_comm_world,num_procs,ierr)
if (myrank==0)then 
    do i=1,max_rows
        vector(i)=i
    end do 
    avg_rows_per_procs=max_rows/num_procs
    do rank=1,num_procs-1
        start_row=rank*avg_rows_per_procs+1
        end_row=start_row+avg_rows_per_procs-1
        if (rank==num_procs-1)end_row=max_rows
        num_rows_to_send=end_row-start_row+1
        call mpi_send(num_rows_to_send,1,mpi_int,rank,101,mpi_comm_world,ierr)
        call mpi_send(vector(start_row),num_rows_to_send,mpi_int,rank,102,mpi_comm_world,ierr)
    end do
    total_sum=0
    do i=1,avg_rows_per_procs
        total_sum=total_sum+vector(i)
    end do
    print*,'Partial sum=',total_sum,'from root process'

    do rank=1,num_procs-1
        call mpi_recv(partial_sum,1,mpi_int,mpi_any_source,103,mpi_comm_world,status,ierr)
        sender=status(mpi_source)
        print*,'Partial sum=',partial_sum,'from rank',sender
        total_sum=total_sum+partial_sum
    end do

    print*,'Total sum=',total_sum
else
    call mpi_recv(num_rows_to_receive,1,mpi_int,master,mpi_any_tag,mpi_comm_world,status,ierr)
    call mpi_recv(vector2,num_rows_to_receive,mpi_int,master,mpi_any_tag,mpi_comm_world,status,ierr)
    partial_sum=0
    do i=1,num_rows_to_receive
        partial_sum=partial_sum+vector2(i)
    end do
    call mpi_send(partial_sum,1,mpi_int,master,103,mpi_comm_world,ierr)
end if 
call mpi_finalize(ierr)    
stop
end program sum_vector
```

Comment: Pleasr write what is the expected answer and what you are getting instead so that we don't have to guess everythinh from your code.

Comment: @Vladimir, my asking is why does this unusual behavior happen?

Comment: Yes, but you did not tell us which behavior. How does it look like? We can't explain why does something happen when you do not say what exactly you mean. You are talking about a correct answer, but you do not say how should the correct answer look like. How is your unusual behavior unusual?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that integer overflow occurs for `total_sum` and `partial_sum` for large `max_rows` because the former become as large as ~ `max_rows**2`. Changing the declaration to

```
use iso_fortran_env, only: int64
integer(int64) :: total_sum, partial_sum
```

and the MPI calls for sending/receiving `partial_sum` as

```
call mpi_recv(partial_sum,1,mpi_long_long_int,mpi_any_source,103,mpi_comm_world,status,ierr)
```

and

```
call mpi_send(partial_sum,1,mpi_long_long_int,master,103,mpi_comm_world,ierr)
```

probably gives the expected result. For example, the result obtained with `max_rows = 100000` and 4 processes (using gfortran 4.7 and openmpi 1.6.5) is

```
Partial sum=            312512500 from root process
Partial sum=            937512500 from rank           1
Partial sum=           1562512500 from rank           2
Partial sum=           2187512500 from rank           3
Total sum=           5000050000
```

and the result with `max_rows = 100000000` is

```
Partial sum=      312500012500000 from root process
Partial sum=      937500012500000 from rank           1
Partial sum=     1562500012500000 from rank           2
Partial sum=     2187500012500000 from rank           3
Total sum=     5000000050000000
```

This code works as long as `max_rows` is less than ~ 2*10^9.

Additional notes:

- The exact answer is `Total sum = max_rows * (max_rows + 1) / 2` (simply a sum from 1 to `max_rows`).
- The maximum number of `integer` is often approximately 2*10^9 (please see [integer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2147483647#In_computing)), so if `max_rows` is greater than 10^5, (10^5)^2 / 2 becomes greater than 2*10^9, which may exceed the limit of `integer`.

Edit: I have changed `integer(8)` to `integer(int64)` so that it will be portable (please see @casey's comment).

Comment: @casey yeah, I am still very bad at this kind stuff so I will try an update later. BTW I am also not very sure whether mpi_long_long_int is portable, although some googling says it represents 64-bit integer.

Comment: @MasrulHudaParvez You don't have to thank in the comments (but you can), but you should accept the answer if you agree with it.